# poliastro epoch: How to specify non-default value?

Tags: python

I've been looking at https://docs.poliastro.space/en/stable/user_guide.html, and am unclear re. how to specify a non-default epoch time.  Exactly what kind of object is this?  Is there a way to convert from `datetime.datetime` to the type of time expected by `Orbit.from_classical`?

P.S. It would be good to have a tag for poliastro.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that one can do something like the following:

```
epoch= [2020, 12, 7, 20, 38]

# Naive datetime is datetime with no timezone information.  Here we 'localize'
# the naive datetime, i.e., convert it to a timezone-specific time:
datetime_local= tz.localize(datetime(*epoch))

# Convert localized datetime to UTC:
datetime_UTC= datetime_local.astimezone(utc)

# Convert to Astropy time on UTC scale:
t= time.Time(datetime_UTC, scale='utc')

...

orbit= Orbit.from_classical(Earth, a, ecc, inc, raan, argp, nu, epoch=t)
```